# Project Euler #8 NOT related to overflow

Tags: c#, .net, algorithm

I too am attempting Project Euler #8.  I know what the right answer is, but I'm getting something different.  I'm using all ulong in a checked block, so this isn't related to overflow.

Here's the problem:

> The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the
> greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.
>
> 73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934
> 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843
> 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511
> 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557
> 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113
> 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749
> 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866
> 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776
> 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243
> 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397
> 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482
> 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474
> 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881
> 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586
> 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042
> 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408
> 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188
> 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606
> 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725
> 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450
>
> Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have
> the greatest product. What is the value of this product?

And here's my implementation (using LinqPad).  I keep getting an answer of **10077696000** but I know the answer is actually **23514624000**;

```
string digit = "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355668966489504452445231617318564030987111217223831136222989342338030813533627661428280644448664523874930358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866701724271218839987979087922749219016997208880937766572733300105336788122023542180975125454059475224352584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397536978179778461740649551492908625693219784686224828397224137565705605749026140797296865241453510047482166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881164271714799244429282308634656748139191231628245861786645835912456652947654568284891288314260769004224219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408071984038509624554443629812309878799272442849091888458015616609791913387549920052406368991256071760605886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725716362695618826704282524836008232575304207529634500";


int numDigits = 13;



ulong answer = 0;
int answerIndex = 0;
int currentIndex = 0;
checked
{
    while (currentIndex <= digit.Length - numDigits)
    {
        var substr = digit.Substring(currentIndex, numDigits);
        if (!substr.Contains('0'))
        {
            ulong product = substr.ToCharArray().Select(x => ulong.Parse(x.ToString())).Aggregate((x, y) => x * y);

            if (product > answer)
            {
                answerIndex = currentIndex;
                answer = product;
                var disp = string.Join(" x ", substr.ToCharArray());
                $"Start Index:\t{currentIndex.ToString().PadLeft(4)}\t\tDigits:\t{disp} = {product}".Dump();
            }
        }
        currentIndex++;
    }
}

$"Answer is: {answer}".Dump();
```

Comment: FYI a better way to do this is to keep a Queue of the 13 digits, the current product and the mx.  Read each character and turn it into a digit.  If the digit is 0 clear the queue and reset the current product to 1 and continue to the next character.  Otherwise multiply it into the current product and if the queue has 13 digits then dequeue the oldest and divide it from the current product, and check if that is more than the max.  Finally enqueue the current number.

Comment: @juharr That makes sense, mathematically.  But the solution by Dmitry with fluent API is simpler and more compact.

Comment: Typically the point of these Euler problems is to come up with the fastest solution, not the most compact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your argument is *incorrect*, something went wrong when you copy pasted and you lost `7`:

```
// current code
string digit = "...227443043556689664895044524452316173185640..." 
// should be
string digit = "...2274430435576689664895044524452316173185640..."
                              ^
                              |
                            missed
```

**Edit:** To spot this I've solved the problem myself:..

```
      string digit = ...;

      int numDigits = 13;

      var result = Enumerable
        .Range(0, digit.Length - numDigits + 1)
        .Select(start => digit
           .Skip(start)
           .Take(numDigits)
           .Aggregate(1L, (s, a) => s * (a - '0')))
        .Max();
```

...And I got the incorrect result (`10077696000`), then I copy pasted data from the original site and got the right outcome (`23514624000`). All I had to do is to compare inputs.

Comment: Makes you wonder how he typed the string.... (there is also an extra `0` at the end but it doesnt matter)

Comment: I'm not sure how you saw that... but that was it.  I must have accidentally deleted it when i was removing the breaks in linqpad.

Comment: @Sam: to spot the problem, I solved the problem myself, got the same incorrect result; then I copied the input from the original site myslef and obtained the right answer. All I had to do is to compare the inputs

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I clearly need to brush on my fluent api.  Your solution is quite compact!